# JQuery Closest Class Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a layout as follows (simplified)

```
<div>
    <div class="msgOutput" id="msg2"></div>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p><input type="file" class="documentFile" id="documentFile2" /></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ... more code here ...
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

And I want to put something in the `div.msgOutput` when the `input.documentFile` changes (There are multiple copies on the page)

There is more code, so I do definitely need to search for the closest `class="msgOutput"`

I know it's something to do with `closest()` or `parent()` or something, but it's not working :/

So far I've tried things like:

```
$('.documentFile').change(function(e){
    ....
    $($(this).attr('id')).parent().children('.msgOutput').attr('id').append('Hello World');
    $(this).closest('div').find('.msgOutput').append('Hello World');
    $(this).closest('div').sibling('.msgOutput').append('Hello World');
    ....
});
```

But it's not working :(. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @PatrickEvans yup I have :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cr94dtk0/

You should put a class or id around the containing div, so that you can do some DOM Traversal

```
<div class="container">
<div class="msgOutput" id="msg2">hi</div>
<form>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p><input type="file" class="documentFile" id="documentFile2" /></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

```
  $(".documentFile").change(function(){
  $(this).closest(".container").find(".msgOutput").text("TEXT GOES HERE");
});
```

Comment: No problem. There are some cool traversing methods here: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ in case you're looking to do anything similar in the future. I find the .offsetParent() method useful from time to time. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You've already found the closest div but you're adding extra selector methods which is screwing your result.

This works:

```
$(this).closest('div').append('Hello World');
```

Comment: The only thing is there are more than 1 div in the code, sorry forgot to mention that. This is just the basic example.

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks, I had, but as far as I was aware people who answer don't get alerted when the question is updated, so I just replied so they know ;)